# Outlook login script in python3: Javascript not enabled - cannot login

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, python-requests

I am currently trying to log into an outlook account using requests only in Python. I did the same thing with selenium before, but because of better performance and the ability to use proxies with it more easily I would like to use requests now. The problem is that whenever I send a post request to the outlook post URL it returns a page saying that it will not function without javascript.

I read on here that I would have to do the requests that javascript would do with requests, so I used the network analysis tool in Firefox and made requests to all the URLs that the browser made requests to. It still returns the same page, saying that js is not enabled and it will not function without js.

```
s = requests.Session()

s.headers.update ({
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Host": "www.login.live.com",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36",
})

url = "https://login.live.com/"
r = s.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
#Simulate JS
sim0 = s.get("https://logincdn.msauth.net/16.000.28299.9
#...requests 1-8 here
sim9 = s.get("https://logincdn.msauth.net/16.000.28299.9/images/Backgrounds/0.jpg?x=a5dbd4393ff6a725c7e62b61df7e72f0", allow_redirects=True)

post_url = "https://login.live.com/ppsecure/post.srf?contextid=EFE1326315AF30F4&bk=1567009199&uaid=880f460b700f4da9b692953f54786e1c&pid=0"

payload = {"username": username}
sleep(4)
s.cookies.update({"logonLatency": "LGN01=637025992217600244"})
s.cookies.update({"MSCC": "1567001943"})
s.cookies.update({"CkTst": "G1567004031095"})
print(s.cookies.get_dict())
print ("---------------------------")
print(json.dumps(payload))
print ("---------------------------")
rp = s.post(post_url, data=json.dumps(payload), allow_redirects=True)
rg = s.get("https://logincdn.msauth.net/16.000.28299.9/images/arrow_left.svg?x=a9cc2824ef3517b6c4160dcf8ff7d410")
print (rp.text)
print (rp.status_code)
```

If anyone could hint me in the right direction on how to fix this I would highly appreciate it! Thanks in advance

Comment: damn i checked it out and they've REALLY made it complicated.. the tokens required for the login are generated by some complicated javascript.. the js file is huge and it's gonna take some time to figure out what the fuck it's doing, but it's NOT impossible. I would recommend you just stick to selenium on this though. I'm not very familiar with it but you could try logging in with ```Selenium``` then using the generated session cookies to do the rest with ```requests```. That way you don't have to waste a lot of time deciphering the messy js file (which they might even change in the future)

Comment: This seems like a good idea, thank you! I will try it out, hope it works, as I will use proxies that do not work with selenium so I hope they do not link the generated tokens with the IP you use